# Update datetime and a string in Memo field using Java and UCanAccess

Tags: jdbc, sql-update, ucanaccess, memo

I want to update datetime and a string in Memo field using UCanAccess. For example - 5/27/2015 System : some string, this is all I have to update in memo field.

What I have tried - I am converting date to a string using following code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();              
String reportDate = df.format(today);
```

and then using update query of ucanaccess like this:

```
st.executeUpdate(" update tblCaseInventory set fldContactNotes = " + reportDate   + "' System : CAR Report '" +  "  where fldCaseNumber = " +  rs1.getInt("fldCaseNumber"));
```

but I am getting an error:

> Unexpected token : System.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `PreparedStatement` to run a *parameterized query*, something like this:

```java
String sql = 
        "UPDATE tblCaseInventory " +
        "SET fldContactNotes=? " +
        "WHERE fldCaseNumber=? ";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");                                                   
    java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();              
    String reportDate = df.format(today);
    ps.setString(1, reportDate + " System : CAR Report");
    ps.setInt(2, rs1.getInt("fldCaseNumber"));
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much Gord Thompson. That's worked perfectly. But for can you suggest me some link for future where can I find syntax like this for ucanaccess. I couldn't find much documentation on ucanaccess.

Comment: That is standard procedure for JDBC; it is not specific to UCanAccess. Check out the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).